# When the send operation is finished on non blocking socket?

Tags: sockets, nonblocking

Let's suppose that `sock` is an unix socket opened in non-blocking mode and following function

```
void send_int(int sock, int flags) {
    int x = 0xff;
    send(sock, &x, sizeof(int), flags);
}
```

Is this code "correct"? I'm not sure whether the buffer (`x`) is copied into some sending buffer before send returns, or there is a chance that `send` and `send_int` return too early and then non-existing buffer is used as it was only on stack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not necessary to preserve the user send buffer till the send operation is completed in non-blocking mode. So your code is fine.

Internally, the send buffer is copied to the Socket Buffer (SKB) send queue and over to the kernel space.

References:

- The [send manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendmsg.2.html) does not mention of such a need
- Dave Miller's [How SKB's work](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html)